# AutoMapper: What is the Difference Between ForMember and ForSourceMember?

Tags: automapper

I'm new to AutoMapper, so this is probably a beginner's question. I've searched, but haven't seen this discussed. When creating a map, what is the difference between the ForMember and ForSourceMember methods:

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<Role, RoleDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Users, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForSourceMember(x => x.Users, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I'm maintaining code written by others. In some places, I see ForMember, in others ForSourceMember, and as shown above, in one place both.

What's the difference between the two?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at the method signatures. In ...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Role, RoleDto>()
           .ForMember(x => x.Users, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForSourceMember(x => x.Users, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

... `ForMember` is a method that expects an `Expression<Func<RoleDto>>` parameter named `destinationMember`, whereas `ForSourceMember` expects an `Expression<Func<Role>>` parameter named `sourceMember`. So

- `ForMember` configures members of the target type.
- `ForSourceMember` configures members of the source type.

In your case, both the source and the target types have members `UserId`, so the calls *look* the same, but they aren't. They should *do* the same thing, but the funny thing is that `ForSourceMember` doesn't seem to have any effect in ignoring members. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks Gert. That helped me understand how AutoMapper really works.

Comment: I disagree with the comment that 'ForSourceMember doesn't seem to have any effect in ignoring members.'.  I believe it does when you have MemberList.Source set as the validation option (not sure about the terminology here, hope you follow.)

Comment: @Zoop You are incorrect, it will map the data in that case too. It's apparently used for "reverse mapping"